# Purpose of a public repository workspace in rtc

Tags: rtc

In RTC what is the purpose of using  public repository workspace in rtc.

1) will all the users be able to check in the data to the public repository workspace.

2) will all the users be able to deliver the code to the connected stream.

3) How to get the incoming changes from another user.?

Comment: You still have *not* read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer: it is important. http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote is important too.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/24859/basics-purpose-of-a-public-repository-workspace):

> The idea of using a public repository workspace is to provide an up and running development environment for the team.
>   I do not want a developer to spend 2-3 hours with the support of somebody else to setup his workspaces, to run a web application with the J2EE artifacts.
>   Currently we are using MAVEN to build are applications and setting up the development environment and we are struggling with it. To much knowledge required by the developer and way to much money trying to automagically configure the RAD 7.5 workspace with MAVEN and are own scripts.
>
> The idea is to setup pre-configured public repository workspace with all the necessary RAD 7.5 artifacts (server, EAR configuration, web configuration, link between projects and link to MAVEN repository for component that you don't want to load in your workspace.

I prefer my repos workspace to be scoped (never private though, or only the admin can access it and deliver changeset that might not have been delivered to the stream)

The [help page](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_creating_ispf_repository_workspace.html) mentions:

> On the New Repository Workspace panel, enter a number for the level of the visibility for the workspace, which determines who can see the workspace.
>
> 1. - Public
>        Everyone with access to the repository is able to see the files and change sets in all public components in this workspace.
> 2. - Private
>        The owner is the only person with read access to the repository workspace. However, change sets in the public components are visible to others.
> 3. - Scoped
>        Everyone with read access in the connected project area can see the files and contents in public components in this workspace.

So:

> 1) will all the users be able to check in the data to the public repository workspace.

No, only the owner can add changesets

> 2) will all the users be able to deliver the code to the connected stream.

Yes

> 3) How to get the incoming changes from another user.?

You can change the flow target of that workspace in order to reference the workspace of another user.

Comment: If the code in public Repository workspace and code in sand box are out of sync is there a possibility to merge the code?

Comment: @user3302323 yes, change the flow target of your own repo workspace to the public one, accept the change sets and merge locally into your own sandbox, then commit and deliver to the stream. Finally, the owner of the public repo workspace will have to accept the changes from the stream.

Comment: If i do not have the access to commit the changes to the repo workspace . how can i directly deliver the code to sand box ?

Comment: @user3302323 why would you not have access, since it is a public repo workspace. If it is scoped, you must be in the same project. And if that repo workspace is private... you need to ask an admin.

Comment: You have given the answer as only the owner can add changesets. Then how the code can be delivered to the stream?

Comment: @user3302323 "the code can be delivered to the stream?" by the owner of the public repo workspace or... by you: redirect your workflow to that repo workspace, accept the changeset locally, then deliver them to the stream.

Comment: thanks for the answers. My earlier understanding was that code flow goes from sand box to repo work space and then to stream that is why i had the confusion.

Comment: @user3302323 yes, the code can also flow from repo workspace to repo workspace (and your sandbox): that way you can get back change set from other user repo workspace, even if they have not yet deliver them to the stream.

Comment: If i am using public repo work space and the code in sand box is modified as below

Comment: Sand box code :

sysout("sand box");

Code in repo workspace : sysout("repo code");

code in stream : sysout("stream code");

How it will reflect in pending changes view ?

Comment: @user3302323 you need to change the flow target of your repo workspace (which by default points to the stream): make it reference another repo workspace and it will reflect the pending changesets.

Comment: So there is no possibility to see the changes from Repo work space and sand box at the same time. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Exact: you can define multiple flow target, but at any given time, only one of those flow targets is marked as current. You see the pending changes only from the current flow target.

Comment: Also flow target can be stream or any other repo workspace. Is it correct?

Comment: Correct, stream and repos workspaces, except for private repository workspaces: you cannot access those.

Comment: If creating the workspace environment the main puropse of public repository , we can also do that by using a private workspace from stream?

Comment: No, a private repo workspace is only visible by his/her owner.

Comment: I meant private workspace for each user or maber in the team?

Comment: No, I prefer scoped repo workspaces, that way those repo workspaces are visible by the team. I would avoid any private one.

Answer (score 0):

Sand box code :

sysout("sand box");

Code in repo workspace :
sysout("repo code");

code in stream :
sysout("stream code");

How it will reflect in pending changes view ?